# VS code is importing renamed packages

Tags: flutter, visual-studio, dart, visual-studio-code

I renamed `Warehouse_edit_repository.dart` to `warehouse_edit_repository.dart`

But when I import the file and try to run the program I get this error

```
 - 'WarehouseEditRepository/*1*/' is from 'package:bhoomi/data/repository/warehouse_edit_repository.dart' ('lib/data/repository/warehouse_edit_repository.dart').
 - 'WarehouseEditRepository/*2*/' is from 'package:bhoomi/data/repository/Warehouse_edit_repository.dart' ('lib/data/repository/Warehouse_edit_repository.dart').
          EditWarehouseBloc(editWarehouseRepository: WarehouseEditRepository())
                                                     ^
lib/screens/project_screens/purch_mgmt_screens/masters/warehouse_screen/warehouse_edit_screen.dart:178:14: Error: Type argument 'EditWarehouseBloc' doesn't conform to the bound 'BlocBase<S>' of the type variable 'B' on 'BlocConsumer'.
 - 'EditWarehouseBloc' is from 'package:bhoomi/bloc/warehouse_view_bloc/warehouse_view_bloc.dart' ('lib/bloc/warehouse_view_bloc/warehouse_view_bloc.dart').
 - 'BlocBase' is from 'package:bloc/src/bloc.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bloc-7.2.1/lib/src/bloc.dart').
Try changing type arguments so that they conform to the bounds.
      child: BlocConsumer<EditWarehouseBloc, EditWarehouseState>(
             ^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_bloc-7.3.3/lib/src/bloc_consumer.dart:61:20: Context: This is the type variable whose bound isn't conformed to.
class BlocConsumer<B extends BlocBase<S>, S> extends StatefulWidget {
                   ^
lib/screens/project_screens/purch_mgmt_screens/masters/warehouse_screen/warehouse_edit_screen.dart:702:58: Error: The argument type 'AddWarehouseModel/*1*/' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'AddWarehouseModel/*2*/'.
 - 'AddWarehouseModel/*1*/' is from 'package:bhoomi/data/model/add_warehouse_repository.dart' ('lib/data/model/add_warehouse_repository.dart').
 - 'AddWarehouseModel/*2*/' is from 'package:bhoomi/data/model/add_Warehouse_repository.dart' ('lib/data/model/add_Warehouse_repository.dart').
                                                  model: model));
                                                         ^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1102

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I deleted vs code, tried writing the code again removing imports and importing again used `as` in imports but doesn't work. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you have `import` statements that are still using the old casing. Try searching for `Warehouse_edit_repository` and `add_Warehouse_repository` across your workspace with the Case Sensitivity setting enabled in VS Code, and correct any that are using the wrong casing.